# Where is my 500GB?

Tags: laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop, manjaro

I have a 500GB Windows 10 laptop. I have installed manjaro i3 on it. Everything was working fine but when I restarted my computer I saw this

[image]

I booted archiso with UFI and list partitions(2) 
What is /dev/loop and what happened? I didn't understand anything. Please help how can I get my 500GB /dev/sda back?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk -l` ran as root?

Comment: Another clarifying question - did you install Manjaro over Win10 or dual boot?

Comment: No dualboot only manjaro

Comment: http://m.imgur.com/Yw2l9tM

Comment: Might just type it.  The <pre > < /pre> tags are just formatting from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issue #1 - [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) is basically a network boot option.  You can probably disable it in your BIOS or at least move it be used after the computer attempts to boot from USB/CD/HDD.

Issue #2 - Pending an answer after fdisk -l result - but my guess is if you're booting from a live ISO, your hard drive is there, just not mounted.

Comment: http://m.imgur.com/zXVTiaU 
/dev/sda1 is usb i think

Comment: My last thought is to check the cables on the drive itself.  Linux isn't seeing the drive at all.  You could also look through the output of `dmesg` to see if there are any errors popping up.

Comment: What should ı look at output od dmesg or a special dmeg command to directly see the problem

Comment: This may get you some erroneous info, but try `dmesg | grep dev`

Comment: This could help http://m.imgur.com/MTmivAm

Comment: I can't boot from dvd too if i could boot from win10 dvd ı think ı could acces to all partitions

Comment: I'm at a loss then.  I'd check the cables/connection of the hard drive.  Beyond that, hopefully some of the more experienced troubleshooters can help out.